# I found something while playing with VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

While I'm trying to learn throw catch I just compiled my code and I found this output what does that mean?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void MightGoWrong() {
     bool error = true;

     if (error) {
       throw 8;
     } 
//   -------------------------
     int main()
     {      
        cout << MightGoWrong;               
        return 0;
     }
```

And output is : 012211A4 what does that mean?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJknu.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOnVu.png)

Comment: `cout << MightGoWrong; ` prints the address of the function; it does not call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling your function.

`cout << MightGoWrong;` is simply printing the *address* of the function. To call it you should do `cout << MightGoWrong();`.